# Tools to replace IO Board Flex Cable Assembly on MacBook Retina

Tags: mac, hardware

What tools do I need to replace an IO Board Flex Cable Assembly (932-00997) for a 2016 MacBook Retina? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need the following speciality tools:

- TR8 Torx Security Driver
- T5 Torx Driver
- P5 Pentalobe Driver
- #00 Philips Screwdriver

You’ll also need generic tools like plastic “spudgers,” pry tools, tweezers, etc.   You can find these tools and instruction guides on [iFixit.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Retina+MacBook+2016+Teardown/62149).

Just a note of caution… I’m the last person to discourage anyone from opening a device and working on it, but if you’re not familiar with the requirements to to the point of not knowing where to find this info, I highly suggest you practice on a dead MacBook prior to opening yours.  These devices are extremely finicky and you could unknowingly cause irreparable  damage.

Comment: Thanks Allan! I ended up taking it to an Apple dealer for repair. I replaced the tracking pad and keyboard on my MacBook Air but I didn't have everything I needed for this replacement of the IO board. Again, thanks for advice.